# jquery jump to next element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to use the jquery next function to click a link to navigate to the next element in an unordered list. What I have is below, but I get a 404 saying it couldn't find [object Object]

```
$('.next').click(function (event) {
    window.location = $('li').next();
});
```

and

```
<div id="nextButton"><a href="#" class="next" id="next">&gt;</a></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you want to navigate to a list element? What should happen?

Comment: What do you mean by 'navigate to an element'?

Comment: `<ul>
<li><a name="item1">item 1</a></li>
<li><a name="item2">item 2</a></li>
<li><a name="item3">item 3</a></li>
</ul>`

In a list similar to that, I would like to click the next link as posted in my original post to go from #item1 to #item2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you posted your code exactly as is, there are a lot of syntax errors. A fixed up version is below:

```
$('.next').click(function (event) { // missing $/jQuery
    window.location = $('li').next();
}); // missing the close parentheses
```

In addition, since you are doing things with jQuery, you might want to consider using something like:

```
// where selector is the selector for the element you are scrolling to
$(window).scrollTop(selector.position().top);
```

**EDIT**

If it's horizontal, you should only need to adjust the scroll code accordingly. e.g.:

```
$(window).scrollLeft(selector.position().left);
```

**EDIT #2**

Here is a very basic example of what I think you are trying to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/FsjkM/

Click the HTML portion and it'll scroll to the next list element (note the changing numbers).

In your actual application you will need to keep track, or calculate, the "current" element to allow for previous/next functionality.

**Final EDIT**

http://jsfiddle.net/FsjkM/1/

I've fleshed it out a bit to give you an idea of how a more complete structure will look. Note that no boundary checking exist -- if you click prev at the start, or next at the end, it'll break.

Comment: I apologize for not saying this before, but it's a horizontal layout. And yes, sorry for the butchered jQuery.. it's correct in my code

Comment: So, would this be valid? I can't seem to get anything out of it when .next is clicked. `$(window).scrollLeft($('li').position().left); `

Comment: @bswinnerton you need to select a single list item -- your `$('li')` selector is most likely picking up more than one. Try something basic like `li:last` to test the code.

Comment: that worked! My issue is that most of the elements are going to be dynamically created. How can I just choose the next element in the list?

Comment: @bswinnerton you need a reference to the current active list item. From there, you can use `nextAll("li:first")` to select the next list item.

Comment: Actually, upon reflection, a simple `next()` will probably be enough.

Comment: I apologize for being so thick-headed with this. As you can tell, I'm new to jQuery. Where would this next() go in respect to the code that you posted above?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code.

1. $('li') will return all 'li' elements so $('li').next() will return an array. You need selector to indicate current selection.
2. next() will return an element, it is not necessarily internal html. you might want to use next().html() I think that was your intent. But it does not mean it will work. Continue reading next. :-)
3. window.location accepts url string (e.g., "http://www.google.com") , not html link (e.g., 
   `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>`)

Hope it helps