# jquery: animate scrollLeft

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm quite new to jquery and can't seem to figure out why my code isn't working. I have a horizontal layout and want to use the scrollLeft() function (which works perfect with this code)

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    currentElement = currentElement.next();
    scrollTo(currentElement);    
});

function scrollTo(element) {
    $(window).scrollLeft(element.position().left);
}
```

But ideally, I would like to animate this so that when #next is clicked there is a nice animated effect to the scroll left function

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    currentElement = currentElement.next();
    scrollTo(currentElement);    
});

function scrollTo(element) {
    $(window).animate({scrollLeft: element.position().left}, 750);
}
```

But to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: scrollLeft() is a jQuery function, which only works on DOM elements. animate() can only work on DOM style attributes, not functions.

Comment: In my situation, I found that some fixed elements cover the both site of ul , and that mistake me the ul is overflow( In fact the ul is not overflow). So I scrollLeft for so many times , and it didn't work. And the reason why is I mistook the ul is overflow which is not.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You'll want something like this:

```
$("#next").click(function(){
      var currentElement = currentElement.next();
      $('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: $(currentElement).offset().left}, 800);
      return false;
   });
```

I believe this should work, it's adopted from a `scrollTop` function.

Comment: Nothing seems to happen. I think it's because you took out the scrollTo function which selects the next element. What I have is a huge ul with multiple li's and the horizontal theme has two buttons #previous and #next, which select the next or previous item in the ul and what I would like.. is to nicely animate that navigation. Here was my original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867914/jquery-jump-to-next-element

Comment: In theory you should just be able to combine the two functions because you run the `.click` function but you're calling the other one within it. Maybe try `$(window)` instead of `$('html, body')`.

Comment: Right, but what I was saying is I think (and I could very well be wrong) that you didn't include the scrollTo function in your above code, so it's not really a function in a function, even with $(window)

Comment: The `scrollTo` function code becomes `$('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: $(currentElement).offset().left}, 800);`, to put your `scrollTo` code in exactly as is, it would be `$(window).animate({scrollLeft: $(currentElement).position().left}, 750);`. However, the other thing you might want to try is turning the `element` part in your `scrollTo` function code to `$(element)`, and seeing if that works.

Comment: why are you returning false?

Comment: @Andrew Peacock `$(window).animate( { scrollLeft : 320 })` is not working on FF or Chrome using jQuery: 1.11.3

Answer (score 47):

First off I should point out that css animations would probably work best if you are doing this a lot but  I ended getting the desired effect by wrapping .scrollLeft inside .animate

```
$('.swipeRight').click(function()
{

    $('.swipeBox').animate( { scrollLeft: '+=460' }, 1000);
});

$('.swipeLeft').click(function()
{
    $('.swipeBox').animate( { scrollLeft: '-=460' }, 1000);
});
```

The second parameter is speed, and you can also add a third parameter if you are using smooth scrolling of some sort.

Comment: What kind of css animation? Scroll left is not a css property

Comment: Scroll to a specific position (ie. `const left = 200;`) like this: `$(element).animate( { scrollLeft: left }, 1000);`